# Вывести данные в select

Tags: yii2, select, вывод

Пишу на фреймворке YII2. Есть контроллер, в котором есть код, передающий во view данные которые есть в таблице.

**Контроллер:**

```
public function actionView($id)
    {
        // Создаем модель
        $modelquest = new SQuizQuestion();
        // Получаем все вопросы
        $question = SQuizQuestion::find()->all();
        // Формируем массив, с ключем равным полю 'ID_REC' и значением равным полю 'NAME_QUEST'
        $items = ArrayHelper::map($question,'ID_REC','NAME_QUEST');

        return $this->render('view', [
            'modelquest' => $modelquest,
            'items' => $items,
        ]);
    }
```

**VIEW:**

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade active" id="home">
       <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-5">
                     <select id="list-assigned" multiple size="20" style="width: 100%">
                            **ВОТ СЮДА НАДО ИХ ВЫВЕСТИ**
                     </select>
              </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Если я вывожу так **(1):**

```
<select id="list-assigned" multiple size="20" style="width: 100%">
       <?php
              foreach ($modelquest as $item):?>
              <option value=""><? echo $item['NAME_QUEST'];?></option>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

То получается что не видно записей, но можно щелкать по строчкам там где они должны располагаться.

Если вывожу вот так **(2):**

```
<select id="list-assigned" multiple size="20" style="width: 100%">
       <?= Html::activeDropDownList($modelquest, 'ID_REC', $items) ?>
</select>
```

То записи выводятся под колонкой, в которой они должны располагаться. Подскажите пожалуйста как их вывести в колонку что бы они были видны и кликабельны как в 1-м варианте.

**Фото 1-го и 2-го варианта:**
[image: Фото]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `activeDropDown` или `dropDown` если вам не надо модель:

```html
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade active" id="home">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-5">
                                <?= Html::activeDropDownList($modelquest, 'ID_REC', $items, ['multiple' => true, 'size' => 20, 'style' => 'width: 100%']) ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

P.S. Проверьте возможно неймспейс для `HTML` надо будет указать, не помню точно какой.

Comment: Добавил результаты в вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Не заметил select тег, обновил ответ, проверьте теперь

Comment: Да, спасибо, все заработало